# What determines whether applications can broadcast to multiple AirPlay speakers?

Tags: airplay

Some apps, like Remote.app, can broadcast to multiple Airplay speakers at once. Others seem limited to one speaker at a time. Is there a way to enable apps that use Airplay to have the option to broadcast to multiple speakers at once, like Remote app can?

Comment: Are these Mac or iOS apps of which you speak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't directly a feature of Remote.app but of iTunes on the desktop, Remote.app just gives an UI for this. At this time, only iTunes running on Mac/Windows or other desktop apps like [Airfoil](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) are able to distribute to multiple speakers at once.